# iOS11:How can I use Vision framework track face across video?

Tags: vision, ios11

i can track object across video ,but i can't track face.
when i use camera track face . the code print []

```
extension FaceTrackingViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    let request = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest { [unowned self] request, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.presentAlertController(withTitle: self.title,
                                        message: error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            print("\(request.results!)")
        }
    }


    do {
        try handler.perform([request], on: pixelBuffer!)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you have init ur `VNImageRequestHandler` with sampleBuffer before you can call `perform` method